# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException -1 when checking last letter of a word

Tags: java, exception, outofrangeexception

I'm trying to solve a problem on coding bat and cannot pass one test.

Given a string, count the number of words ending in 'y' or 'z' -- so the 'y' in "heavy" and the 'z' in "fez" count, but not the 'y' in "yellow" (not case sensitive). We'll say that a y or z is at the end of a word if there is not an alphabetic letter immediately following it. (Note: Character.isLetter(char) tests if a char is an alphabetic letter.)

Here is my code:

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
int count = 0;
str = str.toLowerCase();
String[] newArr = str.split("[\\s:0-9-!]+");
for (String word : newArr) {
  if (word.charAt(word.length() - 1) == 'y' || 
    word.charAt(word.length() - 1) == 'z') {
    count++;
    }
  }
    return count;
}
```

However I cannot pass this test and it shows this error:

countYZ("!!day--yaz!!") → 2

`Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 (line number:6)`

Comment: Obviously one of the Strings in your array is empty.

Comment: @Eran is correct. An easy fix is using `word.endsWith("y") || word.endsWith("z")`. This works for empty word strings too (yields false as expected).

Answer (score 1):

`Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 (line number:6)` means that you're calling `-1`th index.

You're calling always `charAt(word.length()-1)` so if `word.length()-1 == -1`, `word.length() == 0`. Add a check if `word.length()>0` before checking last letter.

It's caused by the following slicing:

```
!!day--yaz!!
["day", "yaz", ""]
```

For example you can write:

```
for (String word : newArr) {
  if (word.length() > 0 && (word.charAt(word.length() - 1) == 'y' || 
    word.charAt(word.length() - 1) == 'z')) {
    count++;
    }
  }
    return count;
}
```

or simpler (according to [Ole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v)'s idea):

```
for (String word : newArr) {
  if (word.endsWith("y") || word.endsWith("z")) {
    count++;
    }
  }
    return count;
}
```